# Animating ImageView in selected listview to appear in another fragment in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, imageview, android-animation

I have a ListView with an adapter that adds different ImageViews vertically. I am able to open and close a fragment (a different screen on top of listview) upon each ListView selected item.

However, now I want to bring over the ImageView of the selected item to the fragment in an animated way. I have tried implementing the "zooming a view" tutorial, but it does not seem to work.

[The end result would exactly be like to this, but I need the squared imageview to morph into a rectangle at the end](https://media.giphy.com/media/l1J9xvJOxKHTKRF9m/giphy.gif)

Am I supposed to use a gridlayout instead?

Comment: so many tutorials are available, might this link help you 
https://medium.com/@andkulikov/animate-all-the-things-transitions-in-android-914af5477d50

Comment: have you tried shared element transition ?